# Como mostrar id y name en option from collection Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

necesito mostrar en mi option los campos id y name juntos. Lo que tengo realizado es lo siguiente, pero esto solo me va  a mostrar el 'id'. Hay alguna manera de hacer lo que necesito?

> select_tag "provider", options_from_collection_for_select(Provider.actives, :id, :id ) , class: "form-control"

Comment: Lo estuve mirando y es lo que me serviría, pero donde defino mi método 'select_attributes', en mi controlador?

Comment: Lo defines en el modelo (clase) `Provider`; el método `options_from_collection_for_select` lo que hace es tomar la colección que especifiques (en tu caso `Provider.actives`) y llama los métodos para el _valor_ y la _descripción_ de cada opción en cada uno de los elementos (en tu ejemplo `id` y `id`).

Comment: Excelente explicacion, muchas gracias. Cuando cargo el formulario donde tengo el options_from_collection_for_select me demora mucho siempre en cargar la pagina, sera por la consulta?

Comment: Probablemente, los problemas de _performance_ suelen ser causados por la base de datos. Si quieres un perfilado más detallado, te recomiendo ver la gema [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler).